# Error 404 api azure translator basic program python

Tags: python, azure, portal, azureportal

I started a translator project on azure.

I copy the simple test code.

```
import os, requests, uuid, json

subscription_key = 'KEY_IN_PORTAL_AZURE'
endpoint = 'URL_IN_PORTAL_AZURE'

path = '/translate?api-version=3.0'
params = '&from=fr&to=en'
constructed_url = endpoint + path + params

headers = {
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key,
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'X-ClientTraceId': str(uuid.uuid4())
}

body = [{
    'text' : 'Bonjour'
}]
request = requests.post(constructed_url, headers=headers, json=body)
response = request.json()

print(json.dumps(response, sort_keys=True, indent=4,
                 ensure_ascii=False, separators=(',', ': ')))
```

I change the key and the endpoint but the program return

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "404",
        "message": "Resource not found"
    }
}
```

I delete the service and i retry same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're 2 errors in the sample code.

**Error 1:** for the endpoint, use this one instead of copying the one from azure portal:

```
endpoint = 'https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/'
```

**Error 2:** in headers, please add `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region`, and it's value is the region of the Cognitive Services resource. Like below:

```
'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region':'EastUS'
```

You can get the region from azure portal, the screenshot is as below:

[image]

And I tested it at my side, it worked. The result as below:

[image]